# java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string:""

Tags: java

I am currently working with an attendance management system, but when I click the "save" button this problem shows up 'java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string:""'
Here is my code:

```
 try{    
          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attendance","root","sydneydel");
     String sql = "insert into attendance.student_info values(?,?,?,?,?)";
          PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()));
          pst.setString(2, last.getText());
          pst.setString(3,first.getText());
          pst.setString(4,mid.getText());

          String gender;
          if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
              gender=jRadioButton1.getText();
          }
          else{
               gender=jRadioButton2.getText();
          }
          pst.setString(5, gender);
          pst.executeUpdate();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCCESSFUL");
          conn.close();
         String data1= last.getText();
        String data2= first.getText();
        String data3= mid.getText();
        String data4= gender;
        Object[] row = {1, data2 + " " + data3 + " " + data1, data4};
        model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow (row);
        first.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        last.setText("");
        mid.setText("");
        buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
        if((last == null)&& (first==null)&& (buttonGroup1.equals(null))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVE ERROR\nFill-up the information needed");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)

       {       
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);  
                 }    
    }
```

How can I resolve my problem and how could I improve this program?

Comment: the problem is that an empty string is not a valid numerical value. here's another one: buttonGroup1.equals(null) -> this is a nullPointerException in the making. if buttonGroup1 is null, this will crash

Comment: I assume this: pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText())); is where you get the error? check if jTextField2 is empty, or provide a default value

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` on the 4th line is receiving an empty string from `jTextField2.getText()`, and of course that is not parseable as an integer.

Use a debugger to figure out why `jTextField2.getText()` is blank. Is a number in fact entered in `jTextField2`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Answer ;)

```
String value = "10";
Integer convertedForm = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

This will works and the value is converted to  `Integer` because value is in number form

But if we pass `""` or `"abc"` like that it can't convert  from that to `Integer` form because we are not passing number. So it will give `NumberFormatException`.

So handle `NumberFormatException` , if you pass other then number